# How to launch another app in the background?

Tags: android, background-process

I'm launching my app on boot up but I want it to start up in the background.

```
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.app");
if (launchIntent != null) {
   context.startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```

Any idea how to do that without the app start up in the foreground?

Comment: background means?

Comment: Not really sure. I guess apps running in the back ground are really just using services.

Comment: you basically need to start service on boot completed action.

Comment: I don't want to run my own app in the background, I want to run another app in the back gourd, which means I need to start up its background service on boot up.

Comment: For this requirement, I guess you have to go for broadcast receivers and I guess that's the only way to communicate between two apps with a tag android:exported="true". Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive messages from sources outside its application — "true" if it can, and "false" if not. If "false".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically an *app* majorly consists of **two** components.

1. **Activity** : Runs in foreground which is mainly a **GUI** for an *app* and user interacts with **activity** as it take inputs from *user* and displays required results.
2. **Service**: Runs in background which does all the operations required by **activity** to produce results by receiving the inputs from **activity**(*user*) and send back the results to **activity** for displaying them.

So, your question of starting an *app* in background ! This can be achieved by starting a **service** of your *app* on *boot up* and carry out tasks which you want to perform.

P.s : To start a **Service** on *boot*-*up*, you will require to set up a **Boot-Receiver**. If you want any further information regarding this, please let me know.

Comment: I want to start up background service of another app. It is possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android see this, but it is regarding launching activity  but not sure for a service.

Comment: For this requirement, I guess you have to go for broadcast receivers and I guess that's the only way to communicate between two apps with a tag android:exported="true". Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive messages from sources outside its application — "true" if it can, and "false" if not. If "false".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Background extends Service { 
//declare variables
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //your code here


    return 1;
}
```

Comment: No I want to start up another apps background service, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: i am not really sure about this but in my opinion that app can only start its own service. please try if broadcast intents solves your problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start it, but **you can use it**

As mentioned in this [android service exported attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944735/android-service-exported-attribute)

**The purpose of the "exported" is to let other apps have access to a service.**

The above post explained it very well. May it will be helpful for others too.